# Spring Boot Application giving 404 after upgrading to springboot 2.6.6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have changed the spring boot version of my web application from 2.1.2 to 2.6.6 . Here is the POM---

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.6</version>
    <relativePath>/</relativePath> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

A1fter version upgrade I faced some circular dependency issues which I resolved using constructor injection with @Lazy annotation. Below is example---

```
@Autowired
public ServiceImpl(@Lazy ABCService abcService,
        @Lazy XYZService xyzService,
        @Lazy PQRMapper pqrMapper,
        @Lazy PQRService pqrRepositoryService) {
    super();
    this.abcService = abcService;
    this.xyzService = xyzService;
    this.pqrMapper = pqrMapper;
    this.pqrRepositoryService = pqrRepositoryService;
}
```

[image]

But if I am trying to hiit any API it is giving me 404.
[image]

Can anyone suggest what I can do to resolve this.

Comment: try to add `@RequestMapping("/")` on class level in the failing controller if it does not already contain it

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos I have added screenshot of my controller pls have a look. Also I am not able to hit even a single API. if I reduce the version same works fine.

Comment: Please don't post code as images but rather as code. You are upgrading 5 versions and haven't read the upgrade guides, which is probably the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue after going through all the release documents, I figured out that spring-boot disables the default-dispatcher-servlet. so we need to enable it with property-

> server.servlet.register-default-servlet=true

This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

in log there is info `exposing one endpoint beneath base path '/internal'`

maybe those controllers you try to use are not created maybe package is not scaned

Comment: I have Added the component scan on Main Class.
ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.odigo.outbound.*", "com.odigo.common.*"})